# Why was this question about WebKit alternatives closed as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

I got an upvote on [this old question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606182/what-are-the-x-webkit-speech-alternatives), and when I went to see it, I realized it was closed as off-topic. To me, it is perfectly fine question.

[A simple search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=border-radius%20alternative) revealed a number of questions on the same lines. Why was this one closed as off-topic?

Comment: Did you read the close reason? It explains why.

Comment: plz read the reason. Its not relevant. I was asking a perfectly valid question. Code works on one browser but not on another.

Comment: Don't assume community moderation is perfect and will catch all cases of posts that are on-topic. Certainly, don't use other questions that are off-topic  as still open as a reason to request re-opening. If a post is to be re-opened, it will be done on the merits of the post itself and the current rules on what is on- or off-topic.

Comment: @aWebDeveloper: Then *ask about that*. Explain *in this post* why you think the post should be re-opened. Consider editing the question to remove the request for a list of software. Focus on *how you tried to solve the problem* instead.

Comment: not asking it to be reponed. Just pointing out an error

Comment: @aWebDeveloper: no, the post was not closed in error. It is definitely off-topic by current standards.

Comment: ... that seems rather pointless. Either you invest some effort into it based on the advice you get there ... or you just don't bother at all.

Comment: @Martijn is it, though? It's not asking for software, but an HTML attrribute...

Comment: @CodeCaster: not as worded. It is asking for other browsers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thats what i want to know why it's off topic

Comment: I have edited the question so it doesn't sound off-topic anymore. Feedback welcome.

Comment: Much better @CodeCaster. And seconds before I was finished. :D

Comment: Valid question != On-topic question.

Comment: Closely related: [Let's rescue wayward resource requests! (trial run)](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341987)

Comment: @CodeCaster: thanks, I've re-opened the question.

Comment: @aWebDeveloper because it wasn't written clearly enough for people to see that it WASN't a resource request. Explaining how that closure is wrong is fantastic, but If the post isn't edited (as codecaster did),then it still looks like a resource request. On hold is the signal to you that you should edit your Q.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is an old question. It was bumped by [a new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34675398/1743880), which is quite poor: at the very least link-only (it just consists of links to some products) and border-line spam.

I probably reviewed this new answer thanks to the [New Answers to Old Questions moderator tool](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions), available to users with more than 10k of reputation. Reviewing it led me to the question, which is a request for off-site resources, as it is asking for browsers implementing an alternative to Webkit speech input. Such questions are off-topic for the site, and I consequently voted to close it, [passing a cv-pls request in the SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/28005383#28005383), because I felt that, because of this new activity, a fast closure was needed. As worded, such questions tend to attract those kind of poor answers, and this is why they should be closed.

When you think your question has been misunderstood / wrongly closed, **edit it**. Focus on the actual problem you're having. It has now been edited, and reopened, to focus on using `x-webkit-speech` in non-Webkit browsers, instead of asking for some 3rd party softwares, which is perfectly on-topic and isn't bound to attract such kind of new spammy answers.

There are indeed lots of other questions that could follow the same pattern... and maybe they should be closed / edited as well. Don't use other questions as examples, maybe they didn't gain new activity, were forgotten, weren't closed when posted, etc.

Comment: I wouldn't focus on using `*-webkit-*` properties on non webkit browsers, since those are webkit exclusive ;).

Comment: @Braiam not any more they aren't, both Firefox and Edge support a whole slew of them.

Comment: @RobertLongson I think you are missing the point of my comment: the webkit properties are normally aimed to work as webkit developers meant them to be. Now, firefox is being a nice guy and the started to map "-webkit- prefix property mappings to their standard equivalents" so lazy developers that don't update their css rules (or care about browser compat) can have a presentable web pages in Firefox too. So, it's better to ask, not about the `-webkit-` prefixed property, but about what the property does.